# polymer style module not working

Tags: polymer-1.0

I am trying to use the Selectize jQuery plugin in a Polymer element, wrapping the selectize CSS and JS files in selectize-css.html and selectize-js.html for importing.  The JS import works, but the *style module* (https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#style-modules) for the CSS does not.  The selectize CSS rules are not matching the HTML generated by selectize inside the Polymer element.

Here is my element:

```
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.4/css/selectize.bootstrap3.css"> -->
<link rel="import" href="./selectize-css.html">
<link rel="import" href="./selectize-js.html">

<dom-module id="subject-picker">
    <template>
    <style include="selectize-css"></style>
    <select id="selector" value="{{selection::change}}">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Pick a number...</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
        <option value="5">Five</option>
    </select>

</template>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'subject-picker',

        properties: {
            selection: {
                type: String,
                notify: true
            }
        },
        attached: function () {
            var _this = this;
            $(this.$.selector).selectize({
                // When the user selects a different option, update the selection property.
                onChange: function (newValue) {
                    if (_this.selection != newValue) {
                        _this.selection = newValue;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
</dom-module>
```

And here is the selectize-css.html style module:

```
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="selectize-css">
<template>
    <style>
       // contents of selectize.bootstrap3.css go here
    </style>
</template>
</dom-module>
```

If I include the CSS directly rather than with a style module (uncomment second line of element code), the CSS does work properly.  I have gotten style modules to work in other cases, but cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here.  Any ideas?

Thanks,
Dennis

Comment: Hmm, can you add a `<style>:host { display: block; }</style>` also to your template after you include the shared styles? I don't see why this should not work, maybe it's a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Polymer style modules started working after I set the global dom setting to "shadow":

```
<head>
<script>
    /* see https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#style-modules */
    window.Polymer = {
        dom: 'shadow'
    };
</script>
```

Comment: This is not an answer, and as such shouldn't be posted as one. You'd be better off editing the original question and adding this info.